# Text report testing with Java application

Tags: java, parsing, reporting, text-parsing

I am working on a project that I have to check if some(500) reports, generated from a system, are passed or failed.

I face 2 problems.

1. Text-parsing. Each report is unique and has different formats.

report example :

Ticket sales

Movies      Full_seats  Sales       Empty_seats

Movie 1
Monday      100     500     20

Tuesday     120     600     0

Wednesday   80      400     40

Thursday    100     500     20

Friday      100     500     20

Movie 2

Monday      100     500     20

Tuesday     120     600     0

Wednesday   80      400     40

Thursday    100     500     20

Friday      100     500     20

and so on...

end of report.

What can I do in order to map the values from the report, and save them into java collection. Is there a more clever way that to create 500 different parsing methods?

2. compare  the reports with the information from the app. I want to have a configuration file for each report and within that to write what do I need to compare from the app. for example:

report.grossSales & sales.getDay(18_9_2016).grossSales();

the above will mean for the automation to run:

```
if(report.grossSales != sales.getDay(18_9_2016).grossSales()){
  System.out.print("failed");
}
```

Feel free to suggest other ways, more clever and flexible.
Thank you

Comment: Are these inputs defined or are they arbitrary lines?

Comment: the system that generates the reports and my app have the same input(tickets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReadFile {
  public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

      FileReader in = new FileReader("C:/test.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
      String line = "";
      String wholeReportText="";
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         wholeReportText += line;
      }
      in.close();

           Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Movies(.*?)");
           Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(wholeReportText);
           // check all occurance
           while (matcher.find()) {
                   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
           }

      Pattern daypat = Pattern.compile("Tuesday (.*?)");
      Matcher daymat = daypat.matcher(wholeReportText);
      // check all occurance
      while (daymat.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
      }


  }
}
```

Your Problem needs to be broke in sub problems as in case of algorithms

> Step 1) To list all the files which you need to parse (File API in
>   java FileFilter in java NIO and Paths API in java7)
>
> Step 2) Read and extract data from file one by one  (sample code
>   above)
>
> Step 3) Store the extracted data in some HashMap or ArrayList
>
> Step 4) Use collections as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you task is to verify whether report file was generated and saved correctly.
In this case I wouldn't complicate you automation app.
You probably have access to algorithm/templates that generates report files.
So report can be generated in-memory and then its content can be easily verified with what you have in file.

Comment: I dont have access to the templates or the database. What I have is the same input(tickets) in both my app and the normal system.Then I get the reports from the system and I have to test them against the app..

Answer (score 1):

You can create different parsing mechanism for each type of ticket. For example, you can have interface:

```
interface Ticket {
    void create(String rawTicket);
    Double getSales();
}
```

And different implementations for all types of tickets, for example:

```
class DayTicket implements Ticket{

    @Override
    public void create(String rawTicket) {
        //parse raw ticket, for example, "Monday 10 10 10"
    }

    @Override
    public Double getSales() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then on input you can provide regex patterns for each type of ticket and iterate all of them finding matching implementation of Ticket which then can take raw text and parse it into meaningful object:

```
//Matches Wednesday 80 400 40
Pattern DAY_TICKET = Pattern.compile("^\\w+day\\s\\d+\\s\\d+(\\s\\d+)?$");

Ticket createTicket(String raw) {
    if (DAY_TICKET.matcher(raw).matches()) {
        Ticket dayTicket = new DayTicket();
        dayTicket.create(raw);
        return dayTicket;
    }
    //etc
}
```

As to regards to 500 different parsing methods you mentioned - you need to have only one for these, for example,

```
Tuesday 120 600 0

Wednesday 80 400 40
```

Thursday 100 500 20

Friday 100 500 20

And extract day and amounts the same way

Comment: yes correct I will reuse the parsing if the report is the same.. and thanks for the solution to use the pattern, do you have any ideas for the configuration file and how to implement that?So I read the tickets from the reports, for example, and then I want to say "tickets price" check against "value from app"